# grouping data in SQL based on date manipulations

Tags: mysql, sql

I've sample data here (date: yyyy-mm-dd format)

```
Headquarter     date       Sales       monthyear
    1        2020-10-30    1000         202010
    1        2020-10-31    500          202010
    1        2020-11-01    1000         202011
    1        2020-11-02    2000         202011
    1        2020-11-03    3000         202011
    1        2020-11-04    1000         202011
    1        2020-11-05    1000         202011
```

I have to sum all the sales values from 2nd of current month to 2nd of next month. Grouping by headquarter and monthyear. So if I run the query, based on current_date(), the sales value should be added to that month respectively.

To brief my explanation, here's the desired result

```
headquarter    sales      monthyear
   1           4500        202010
   1           5000        202011
```

So here 30th, 31st of Oct and 1st, 2nd of Nov falls in my condition and their values are summed to oct month. But 3rd, 4th of Nov values are summed to Nov month. Likewise it happens with every month.
If I run the sql query, as today is 1st Nov (IST), today's value should be added to previous month.

I'm looking for some help in making the SQL query here.

Comment: *I've to sum all the sales values from 2nd of current month ..* inclusive? *.. to 2nd of next month* exclusive?

Comment: exactly. That is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date` - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%y%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL offers the `year_month` specifier for `extract()`.  I assume you want everything from the 2nd of one month to the first of the next month.  If so, subtract one day:

```
select headquarter,
       extract(year_month from date - interval 1 day) as yyyymm,
       sum(sales)
from sample
group by headquarter, yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thanks you the comment. Suppose If I run the query today (my current date 2nd Nov IST), as this falls in the condition of 2nd of Nov month to 2nd of Dec month. This should be added to Nov month. If I run this query on 2nd of Dec, it also falls in the same condition, it should be added to Nov month. can we do this using current_date()? anything like that?

Comment: @NikhilGarakapati . . . The question describes the date column being in the data, so the current date has little to do with it.  If you want to *filter* based on the current date, then that would be a different question.  A similar approach could be used.  If you need help on that, ask a *new* question.